# How to convert an excel file to a text file without corruption in columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, text-editing, notepad

I want to convert a bunch of data from excel to text file. But as you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKa0G.jpg), numbers are not correctly in their columns.
I've tried copying and pasting data into notepad and saving excel as a txt file, but none of them worked well. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to make a.csv file out of it?

Comment: Try exporting as CSV file, and you can clearly see the data, and the delimiters, in a text editor such as Notepad++.

Comment: Notepad doesn't support that kind of formatting, maybe wordpad or a proper text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intended use is creating a file to use for importing data into some other program, your file will function perfectly. The delimiters are present in it and even though it displays poorly on screen, it will not affect the import.

Of course, if the import is a done deed, forever, upon being done and you flat out do not want to risk anything on my answer, you might need to explore whether other formats can be imported. CSV is very old and very likely acceptable, but... may not be.

If your intended use is actually working with the material in a text editor, then you have a problem. Adding tabs to clear up the display, well, adds tabs. If, after working with it, you need to use it for import into another program, that will be a PROBLEM. Of course, editors like NotePad++ offer ways to solve that (using RegEx for example, to find and replace all instances of multiple tabs with a single one, but one can't forget to do it.

And of course, there's no need for it as one can do the work in Excel, then export a .TXT file that is ready for import, not one that needs work. Except... if one is very good with the editor's tools and not with Excel's, that would perhaps not be attractive at all.

But your file is fully usable by programs as is so long as editing for other purposes is not needed. To a program, everything will look to be in the right columns, regardless of how it looks on-screen to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently selecting the cells in Excel and using
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the text.

Excel in this case places the <kbd>Tab</kbd> as delimiter between
the values.
This means that shorter values may not be aligned with longer values
that bypass the tab limit.

To have a tabular result after the copy, you may either:

- Add manually <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters to align better the
  short values
- Paste into a structure that is already tabular.
  For example by creating
  in Word a table with the right number of columns and rows,
  then pasting the Excel data into the table.